# Prove that $f$ is one-to-one an interval

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:(a, b) \to \mathbb R$, has a continuous derivative on $(a, b)$. If $f'(x_0) \ne 0$, prove that there is an interval $(c, d)$ containing $x_0$ such that $f$ is one-to-one on $(c, d)$.